# .Net 4 Chart Controls problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, charts

I am trying to use the example for Real-Time Data charting from below
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart
but although the application gives C# code to copy/paste into your program, I'm getting the following error: no suitable method found to override for a function called Dispose.
Anyone knows what's wrong?

Here's the exact code as it is given by the application. Does someone understand how to use this?

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...
private Thread addDataRunner;
private Random rand = new Random();
private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;
public delegate void AddDataDelegate();
public AddDataDelegate addDataDel;
...

private void RealTimeSample_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    // create the Adding Data Thread but do not start until start button clicked
    ThreadStart addDataThreadStart = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
    addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadStart);

    // create a delegate for adding data
    addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);

}

private void startTrending_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Disable all controls on the form
    startTrending.Enabled = false;
    // and only Enable the Stop button
    stopTrending.Enabled = true;

    // Predefine the viewing area of the chart
    minValue = DateTime.Now;
    maxValue = minValue.AddSeconds(120);

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minValue.ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxValue.ToOADate();

    // Reset number of series in the chart.
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    // create a line chart series
    Series newSeries = new Series( "Series1" );
    newSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    newSeries.BorderWidth = 2;
    newSeries.Color = Color.OrangeRed;
    newSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    chart1.Series.Add( newSeries ); 

    // start worker threads.
    if ( addDataRunner.IsAlive == true )
    {
        addDataRunner.Resume();
    }
    else
    {
        addDataRunner.Start();
    }

}

private void stopTrending_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if ( addDataRunner.IsAlive == true )
    {
        addDataRunner.Suspend();
    }

    // Enable all controls on the form
    startTrending.Enabled = true;
    // and only Disable the Stop button
    stopTrending.Enabled = false;
}

/// Main loop for the thread that adds data to the chart.
/// The main purpose of this function is to Invoke AddData
/// function every 1000ms (1 second).
private void AddDataThreadLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        chart1.Invoke(addDataDel);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public void AddData()
{
    DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

    foreach ( Series ptSeries in chart1.Series )
    {
        AddNewPoint( timeStamp, ptSeries );
    }
}

/// The AddNewPoint function is called for each series in the chart when
/// new points need to be added.  The new point will be placed at specified
/// X axis (Date/Time) position with a Y value in a range +/- 1 from the previous
/// data point's Y value, and not smaller than zero.
public void AddNewPoint( DateTime timeStamp, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries )
{
    double newVal = 0;

    if ( ptSeries.Points.Count > 0 )
    {
        newVal = ptSeries.Points[ptSeries.Points.Count -1 ].YValues[0] + (( rand.NextDouble() * 2 ) - 1 );
    }

    if ( newVal < 0 )
        newVal = 0;

    // Add new data point to its series.
    ptSeries.Points.AddXY( timeStamp.ToOADate(), rand.Next(10, 20));

    // remove all points from the source series older than 1.5 minutes.
    double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds( (double)(90) * ( -1 )).ToOADate();
    //remove oldest values to maintain a constant number of data points
    while ( ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore )
    {
        ptSeries.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddMinutes(2).ToOADate();

    chart1.Invalidate();
}

/// Clean up any resources being used.
protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
{
    if ( (addDataRunner.ThreadState & ThreadState.Suspended) == ThreadState.Suspended)
    {
        addDataRunner.Resume();
    }
    addDataRunner.Abort();

    if( disposing )
    {
        if (components != null) 
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    }
    base.Dispose( disposing );
}       
...
```

Comment: MS Chart Controls give me a headache. </troll>

Comment: No repro.  Document your question with the filename and line number of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the copied code in the correct class. As I know only Classes inherited of Controls (e.g. Forms, UserControls etc.) have a Dispose method.

Just paste your copied Code into a new Form and it should work.

Comment: @chiffre I already did create a new project with a new form and pasted the code but I still cannot make it work. The first problem is that the Dispose method is already defined in the Form1 Designer. I commented that one but I don't know if that's correct. Then the startTrending and stopTrending don't exist so I created two buttons and named them like that. But still, although that the project now compiles, I don't know how to use it to present my data

Comment: It's the way this example works, it displays the current DateTime. For this is the AddData-Delegate used. I think you have to read more of the documentation to solve your problems in this case.

By the way: Your approach of creating 2 buttons seems to be right. But you should really think of learning more of the c#/.net-basics if you really didn't know how to override a method (here: dispose()) etc.

Comment: @chiffre I'm not sure I understand your answer because I didn't ask about the DateTime. I know what the chart is supposed to do. What I don't know very well is how it does it and why it doesn't work as it should.. Could you please run the example and point me to the correct direction? Sorry if this is a beginner's issue but I really need this.

Comment: @chiffre It's true I'm not very familiar with C# but what I just need is to create a chart from real time data and I don't have the time to study C# in deep. I just use my C and Java knowledge and hopefully I'll manage to do what I need.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the time to implement the whole thing now. What I can tell you is: Interesting for adding new Points to the chart is the Method `AddData()` and `AddNewPoint()` in this two methods you have to "insert" the data you wish to display. You'll have to look up for parameterized delegates and thread-invoking

Comment: Yes I know that those are for adding data, but for the specific example, there exists code for adding random data (as it is an example). Anyway the problem is actually how to integrate that example into a new project and then adapt it to your data.. I'll figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to paste all the files, maybe the file named xxxx.designer.cs ?
Sometimes class are defined partials across multiple files.

Comment: There were no files to copy. I downloaded the examples from the download page and run the executable. Inside that application you can choose the chart you want and it gives you the code to copy/paste into your app. I just created a new class and pasted that code and try to compile it but it gives me that error